# What do these symbols mean/what apps do they represent?

Tags: applications

[image]

What do these symbols represent?

Comment: Did you take a look at Settings -> Apps? You might see the icon there and the app name.

Answer (score 9):

*Partial Answer*

---

First one is [Podcast Addict](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bambuna.podcastaddict).

[image]

Comment: The second one is Todoist.

Comment: For the downvoters: this answer was correct until Podcast Addict changed its logo to something else on the Play Store link.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to @vanogrid for the heads up on the second one.

It is [Todoist](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.todoist), and I found the icon with the plus/+ [here](https://d3m2wiud0f58gj.cloudfront.net/f8aae9cea2055a055772476aa07c58f8/as/TODOIST_-_Icon_I_don%27t_want_removed.png). It's a persistent notification that allows you to add a task.

[image: Icon]